# Using Javascript .find() seems to be doing some weird coercion I can't seem to pinpoint

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm trying to collect all the objects from `DATA` and compare to `schemesFromPOI`. If the name is AMERICAN_EXPRESS I want to change it to AMEX in the `scheme` object only, preserving the `DATA` object.

```
const DATA =
    [
      {
        "name": "MASTERCARD",
        "id": "MASTERCARD123"
      },
      {
        "name": "VISA",
        "id": "VISA456"
      },
      {
        "name": "AMERICAN_EXPRESS",
        "id": "AMEX789"
      }
    ];

const schemesFromPOI = [
  { dpaId: 'DPA1', name: 'MASTERCARD' },
  { dpaId: 'DPA2', name: 'VISA' },
  { name: 'AMERICAN_EXPRESS' }
];

let config = [];

schemesFromPOI.forEach(function (schemeFromPOI) {

  let scheme = DATA.find(function (element) { return element.name === schemeFromPOI.name; });

  if(scheme) {
    if (scheme.name === "AMERICAN_EXPRESS") {
      console.log("Before updating scheme.name property: ", DATA);
      scheme.name = 'AMEX';
      console.log("After updating scheme.name property: ", DATA);
    }

    config.push(scheme);
  }

});
```

However, when I change `scheme.name`, the `DATA` object is updated as well. Here is the result of the above console outputs:

```
Before updating scheme.name property: "[{'name':'MASTERCARD','id':'MASTERCARD123'},{'name':'VISA','id':'VISA456'},{'name':'AMERICAN_EXPRESS','id':'AMEX789'}]"
After updating scheme.name property: "[{'name':'MASTERCARD','id':'MASTERCARD123'},{'name':'VISA','id':'VISA456'},{'name':'AMEX','id':'AMEX789'}]"
```

Clearly the `DATA` object is being updated, not just the `scheme` object. Why is this coercion happening? Does it have to do with the `.find()` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [JavaScript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because arrays are reference types. So when you are editing `scheme.name = 'AMEX';`, then it means that `scheme.name` will be changed  and an object which was found in `DATA`.

If you want to create a brand new object, then use spread `...` operator :

```
const data = [
    { name: "John", age: "22", weight: "60", height: "180cm" },
    { name: "Emma", age: "25", weight: "55", height: "160cm" }
];

let obj = data.find(f=> f.name =='John');

let brandNewObject = {...obj};
```

An example:

```js
const data = [
        { name: "John", age: "22", weight: "60", height: "180cm" },
        { name: "Emma", age: "25", weight: "55", height: "160cm" }
    ];
    
    let obj = data.find(f=> f.name =='John');        
    let brandNewObject = {...obj};        
    brandNewObject .name = "Joseph";
    
    console.log(`obj`, obj);
    console.log(`brandNewObject `, brandNewObject );
```

Comment: This works! However spread operator isn't supported by IE, and I have to support that unfortunately. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Using `let scheme = Object.assign({}, obj);` with the IE polyfill instead of the spread operator was a good workaround for me.

Answer (score 1):

This happens in JS we call it with the term Mutable type, you can visit this link for better understanding https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Mutable

To get back to your answer

```
Object.freeze(DATA);
```

The above code will freeze the object and won't allow it to get updated.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in this case.